# Hibernate - How to save Json string in JSONB column

Tags: hibernate

I'm having a json string which i want to save in a JSONB column - either in mysql or postgres via hibernate.

Need a working sample or example for reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References to the official hibernate doc`s says - JSON does not implemented as [basic type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic) , but you can solve this problem with using your [custom type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type). You can use the manual at [this website,](https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/) which can provide you some information about creating your own types for Hibernate annotations.